# Tipado correcto en TypeScript para fechas

Tags: angular, typescript

¿Alguien podría decirme como tipar correctamente una fecha y como inicializarla?
Adjunto el ejemplo en el que tengo un interface en el que uno de los datos es la fecha de nacimiento. Con tipado estricto, necesito inicializarlo pero no se cómo...

¡Muchas gracias!

```
export interface userModel {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    birth: **Date**,
    description: string,
    imgs: string[]
}
```

```
user: userModel =
  {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    birth: **00/00/0000**,
    description: '',
    imgs: []
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export interface userModel {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    birth: Date,
    description: string,
    imgs: string[]
}
```

si ocupas Date tienes que usar el objeto de javascript Date

```
user: userModel =
  {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    birth: new Date('00/00/0000'), // esto da invalid date
    description: '',
    imgs: []
  }
```

se puede pasar un string para que lo convierta, este stringtiene que ser en formato US, MM/dd/yyyy

```
ejemplo: new Date('10/20/2023') // 20 de octubre de 2023
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!